# Using python buitin commands for writing to a file vs using subprocess to run similar shell command

Tags: python-3.x, linux, shell, file, subprocess

If I use python commands, I have to open a file, write to it, then close it.

```
foo = open("file name", w+)
foo.write("blah")
foo.close()
```

By using `subprocess.run`, I can run a linux shell command `subprocess.call(['echo', 'blah', '>', 'foo'])`.

This happens inside an infinite loop repeats every one second, therefore is supposed to take minimum time as possible.

Question is which method should I use?

Comment: Have you tried `subprocess.call(['echo', 'blah', '>', 'foo'])`? Did it work?

Comment: Hmm, there seems to be a problem, `subprocess.call(['echo', 'blah', '>', 'foo'])` gives the message `CompletedProcess(args=['echo', 'blah', '>', 'foo'], returncode=0)` but there was no file created. os.system('echo blah > foo')` on the other hand works! Why is that?

Comment: `>` has special significance in a shell command. `subprocess.call` as written does not run a shell command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is even worse that what you expect! Redirections are a shell operation, so your command will not have the expected result. At best, if it can find an `echo` command in the PATH, it will write `blah > foo` on standard output, at worse, it will fail for not finding the echo command. For the subprocess command to work, you will have to add a `shell=True` parameter.

Then on each operation you will start a new shell to execute the echo command. Starting a process is an expensive operation. If you only loop every second, it would probably not even be noticeable, but it is much more expensive than a direct write to a file.

But the most Pythonic way would be to use a context manager:

```
with open("file name", "w") as foo:
    foo.write('blah\n')
```

Comment: Thank you. `os.system` seems to work, would it be a bad practice to use that?, just asking.